# Dart StreamBuilder initial value

Tags: flutter, dart

To my understanding, `StreamBuilder` is taking 2 things as its arguments:

1. the `stream` itself that will be listened to
2. the `builder`: in here, we are going to define what we want to do when a new data comes from our stream.

From a little bit googling and surfing in stackoverflow, I think my understanding is correct: *`builder` is only getting triggered when a new data comes to the stream.*

I also heard from official video, it is good practice to provide `initial data`, or check `hasData()` and act accordingly. (https://youtu.be/MkKEWHfy99Y?t=52)

My question is, why? and how?
If the StreamBuilder's `build` part is only getting triggered when there is a new event, how come it will get triggered in the beginning, when there are no data. And why should I even bother writing code for it if it will not be triggered?

P.S.
I know that `initial data` and `!hasData()` code works initially, when there is no data. I'm not arguing that **it won't work**. I just want to understand, how it is possible, if the `builder` part is getting triggered ONLY when new data comes.

If so, why do we need to check the case where it doesn't have data initially, and write code for that? Since there are no new data in the beginning

Comment: Actually the builder is not only triggered when new data comes - There is an initial call to the builder which occurs when the StreamBuilder itself is first built. If you don't provide any initialData and the stream is empty, that first snapshot will have no data, but the builder will still be called

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Hope they had provided this info in the official documents/videos as well. Appreciated ^^